# How to correctly add day, hour and minute to existing date

Tags: c#

```
  int serviceday = 0;
                        int servicehour = 0;
                        int serviceminute = 0;

                        if (ServiceDay == null || ServiceDay == "")
                        {
                            serviceday = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            Convert.ToInt32(ServiceDay);

                        if (ServiceHour == null || ServiceHour == "")
                        {
                            servicehour = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            Convert.ToInt32(ServiceHour);

                        if (ServiceMinute == null || ServiceMinute == "")
                        {
                            serviceminute = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            Convert.ToInt32(serviceminute);
```

I am trying to add days, hours and minutes to an existing datetime but using the .addDays, .addHours and .addMinutes methods, the datetime variable stays the same. I know when ever I use the .addDays method I have to assign a new variable for the return value and even that does not change the datetime variable.

```
                        DateTime servicedatetime = new DateTime();
                        servicedatetime = serviceEntry.ServiceDateTime;

                        DateTime newdatetimeDays = new DateTime();
                        DateTime newdatetimeHours = new DateTime();
                        DateTime newdatetimeMinutes = new DateTime();
                        newdatetimeDays = servicedatetime.AddDays(serviceday);
                        newdatetimeHours = newdatetimeDays.AddHours(servicehour);
                        newdatetimeMinutes = newdatetimeHours.AddMinutes(serviceminute);
```

Comment: This line of code ain't doing anything: `Convert.ToInt32(serviceminute);`  Everything looks zero to me.

Comment: You are doing things correctly, are you sure that you are returning the newdatetimeMinutes and not the servicedatetime? Also you don't necessarily need to instantiate a new DateTime for every addition, you can just use newDateTimeDays all the way through for AddDays, AddHours, and Addminutes. Lastly, are you sure that you are actually adding values, and not 0's?

Comment: @NicholasEllingson I realize my mistake, I was not actually not adding the values and only 0's. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsTech You are correct, I noticed that after I posted the question. Sorry everyone for my own mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a lot more compact code

```
int serviceday;
int servicehour;
int serviceminute;
Int32.TryParse(ServiceDay, out serviceday);
Int32.TryParse(ServiceHour, out servicehour);
Int32.TryParse(ServiceMinute, out serviceminute);
DateTime finalDateTime = serviceEntry.ServiceDateTime
                        .AddDays(serviceday)
                        .AddHours(servicehour)
                        .AddMinutes(serviceminute);
```

(NOTE: The bulk of this answer is taken from DavidG one that should take the credits, just to fix that noisy block of ifs to discover if you have or not a valid value)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to add an arbitrary amount of days, hours and minutes but are going the long way round. You can do this all in one go:

```
DateTime finalDateTime = serviceEntry.ServiceDateTime
    .AddDays(serviceday)
    .AddHours(servicehour)
    .AddMinutes(serviceminute);
```

Comment: Or: `servicedatetime.Add (new TimeSpan (serviceDay, serviceHour, serviceMinute, seconds: 0));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the `Convert.ToInt32` calls, otherwise the variables are not set, eg:

```
serviceDay = Convert.ToInt32(ServiceDay)
```